# Twitter's live streaming API unauthorized(android)

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-streaming-api

I found this old android example code that can filter tweets from Twitter's live streaming API according to the input of user, but the problem is that it uses the basic authorization.

Obviously it wouldn't work and I got the "401 unauthorized" error.

Here is the original code:

```
package com.teleknesis.android.twitter.livestream;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TwitterLiveStreamingActivity extends Activity {

    private List<HashMap<String,String>> mTweets = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
    private boolean mKeepRunning = false;
    private String mSearchTerm = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mTweets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"Tweet", "From"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.Tweets)).setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }


public void startStop( View v ) {
    if( ((Button)v).getText().equals("Start") ) {
        mSearchTerm = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchText)).getText().toString();
        if( mSearchTerm.length() > 0 ) {
            new StreamTask().execute();
            mKeepRunning = true;
            ((Button)v).setText("Stop");
            }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must fill in a search term", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    else {
        mKeepRunning = false;
        ((Button)v).setText("Start");
        }
    }


    private class StreamTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        private String mUrl = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=";

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), creds);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=" + mSearchTerm));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) );

        parseTweets(reader);

        in.close();  

        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Twitter", "doInBackground_" + e.toString());
        }
    return new Integer(1);
    }


private void parseTweets( BufferedReader reader ) {
    try {
        String line = "";
        do {
            line = reader.readLine();
            Log.d("Twitter", "Keep Running: " + mKeepRunning
                    + " Line: " + line);
            JSONObject tweet = new JSONObject(line);
            HashMap<String, String> tweetMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (tweet.has("text")) {
                tweetMap.put("Tweet", tweet.getString("text"));
                tweetMap.put("From", tweet.getJSONObject("user")
                        .getString("screen_name"));
                mTweets.add(0, tweetMap);
                if (mTweets.size() > 10) {
                    mTweets.remove(mTweets.size() - 1);
                    }
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                publishProgress(1);
                }
            } while (mKeepRunning && line.length() > 0);
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }



        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) {

            }

        }
}
```

I try to replace the credential with the OAuth:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("*************");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*************");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("*************");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*************");
```

Didn't work..(I have all the correct keys and secrets)

I also tried to insert this whole part into one currently operational twitter client(I can get all the tweets on timeline and all), I don't know if I did it right but it didn't work either. Also in this case, if the Oauth was done again in this code and it worked, does that mean when I run the application I have to be redirected to the authorization page twice if I wanted to use this filter function? I would love a fix that the twitter feed can be used by both the timeline and this filtering mode.

Would anybody shed some lights on how I can do this?

Comment: In order to use OAuth, you need to add a HttpHeader including an `AUTHORITATION` field with value `"Bearer " + your_token`, as explained in [twitter docs for application auth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only). Sorry I cannot test it, not so familiar with the raw org.apache.http.* (I would post it as an answer if I could test it....) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Irnzcig :) but I am not sure I understand what you mean(I am totally new on this :( )..In this specific example I thought a slight modification can be applied to get pass the authorization problem? Or would it be possible that if I insert it somehow into this twitter client I talked about so that it can directly use the stream that the client already get?

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, you have to modify your method `doInBackground` and, instead of adding your credentials, you have to add the authorization parameter to the `HttpHeader`. As I said, I'm not so familiar with org.apache.http.*, I could provide a example with a Jersey client. Yesterday I spent a little time browsing but I did not find anything useful. Now it is evening for my timezone. Maybe I'll spend some more time tomorrow looking for a simple example, but I cannot promise.

Comment: It's so kind of you thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Here is the modified code:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
                CONSUMER_SECRET);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=" + mSearchTerm));
        consumer.sign(request);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) );

        parseTweets(reader);

        in.close();  


        }
```

Comment: wheres CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer coming from?

Comment: I'm getting this error {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]} with this code